# how dynamically update listbox entry in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to update a listbox line, based on a condition, but get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "Wednesday  15      April    2020 ": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number
```

These are the script lines. I get the same error when I use i, or tk.END with listboxMain.delete

```
for i, dt in enumerate(daterange(date1, date2)):
        holiday = us_holidays.get(dt)
        if not holiday:
            holiday = ""

        day, date, month, year = dt.strftime('%A %d %B %Y').split()
        line = f'{day:10s} {date} {month:>10s} {year:>7} {holiday}'

        if (datetime.date.today() - dt).days == 0:
            TODAY_INDEX = i

        listboxMain.insert(tk.END, line)

        for b in list_birthdays:
            if b == dt:
                listboxMain.delete(i, line) <====== Error is here.
                listboxMain.insert(i, line + " Birthday of ")
                listboxMain.itemconfig(i, {'bg': '#999966'})
                listboxMain.itemconfig(i, {'fg': '#000066'})
                break

    listboxMain.itemconfig(TODAY_INDEX, {'bg': '#cc9900'})
    listboxMain.itemconfig(TODAY_INDEX, {'fg': '#000099'})
```

Comment: `listbox.delete` takes the first and last **indices** as parameters, with last optional.  Does `listboxMain.delete( i )` work.  `line` in the code is a string not an index.

Comment: @TlsChris, Yes, now the code works!. Thank you!